# How to fix this header background? It resizes according to the window

Tags: html, css

To be honest I am very new to HTML/css so forgive me if I could not be specific. See the right side of the page. The elements are fine but the background bar changes size according to the page. If I maximize the page then everything is fine.
Here is the jsbin link: https://jsbin.com/qaxaxo/edit?html,output
thanks in advance for helping, I am really stuck here.

Comment: Yes, it does. So? What you wanna happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you must define a `min-width` attribute for `#container` in CSS look below :

```
#container {
 min-width:1270px; /* Or whatever is minimum size of header */
 width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Yup that did the job.... Thanks Farsad. Much appreciated

Comment: If an answer resolve your problem there is always an accept button :)